# KineticJS - Pass DOM element to constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

According to the documentation of Kineticjs the container of the stage can be either a string with an elment's id, or a DOM element. So I wonder why this doesn't work:

```
stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: $(".my-element"),
    width: 200,
    height: 200
});
```

I have verified that .my-element exists and all. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'appendChild'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a jQuery object instead of an html element.

So do this instead which gets the actual html element:

```
container: $(".my-element")[0],
```